# some plotly dash figure stop showing after deploying the app to heroku

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, plotly, plotly-dash

I just deployed a Plotly dash app on Heroku. The whole app is working perfectly fine on my local machine but some figures stop showing after I deployed it on the web. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

**This is how the app looks like on the web -**

[image]

**But working fine on my machine -**

[image]

**Some figures are working fine locally as well as on the web -**

[image]

**The code I am using to plot the figure that is not showing-**

```
controls = dbc.Card(
    [
        # html.H4("Model Input"),
        dbc.CardHeader(
            "Model Input",
            className="bg-primary text-white",
        ),
        html.Br(style={"margin-bottom": "20px"}),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [
                dbc.Label("Month", size="md"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="month-selector",
                    options=[{"label": col, "value": col} for col in month_cols],
                    value="Month__Sep",
                ),
            ],
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [
                dbc.Label("Visitor Type", size="md"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="visitor-type-selector",
                    options=[{"label": col, "value": col} for col in visitor_type_cols],
                    value="VisitorType__New_Visitor",
                ),
            ],
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [
                dbc.Label("Page Value", size="md"),
                # dbc.Input(
                #     id="page-value-input",
                #     value="37",
                #     type="text",  # passing numbers causing unexpected behaviour
                #     debounce=True,
                # ),
                dcc.Slider(
                    id="page-value-input",
                    min=0,
                    max=300,
                    step=1,
                    value=10,
                    marks={
                        0: "0",
                        30: "30",
                        90: "90",
                        150: "150",
                        210: "210",
                        300: "300",
                    },
                ),
                # dbc.FormText("Enter a value between $0 to $300.", color="secondary"),
            ],
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [
                dbc.Label("Exit Rate", size="md"),
                # dbc.Input(
                #     id="exit-rate-input",
                #     value="0.03",
                #     type="text",  # passing numbers causing unexpected behaviour
                #     debounce=True,
                # ),
                dcc.Slider(
                    id="exit-rate-input",
                    min=0.0,
                    max=1.0,
                    step=0.01,
                    value=0.05,
                    marks={
                        0: "0",
                        0.1: "0.1",
                        0.3: "0.3",
                        0.5: "0.5",
                        0.7: "0.7",
                        0.9: "0.9",
                        1: "1",
                    },
                ),
                # dbc.FormText("Enter a value between 0 and 1"),
            ]
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [
                dbc.Label("Bounce Rate", size="md"),
                # dbc.Input(
                #     id="bounce-rate-input",
                #     value="0",
                #     type="text",  # passing numbers causing unexpected behaviour
                #     debounce=True,
                # ),
                dcc.Slider(
                    id="bounce-rate-input",
                    min=0.0,
                    max=1.0,
                    step=0.01,
                    value=0.0,
                    marks={
                        0: "0",
                        0.1: "0.1",
                        0.3: "0.3",
                        0.5: "0.5",
                        0.7: "0.7",
                        0.9: "0.9",
                        1: "1",
                    },
                ),
                # dbc.FormText("Enter a value between 0 and 1")
            ],
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [
                dbc.Label("Product Related", size="md"),
                # dbc.Input(
                #     id="product-related-input", value="34", type="text", debounce=True
                # ),
                dcc.Slider(
                    id="product-related-input",
                    min=0,
                    max=200,
                    step=1,
                    value=18,
                    marks={
                        0: "0",
                        30: "30",
                        60: "60",
                        90: "90",
                        150: "150",
                        200: "200",
                    },
                ),
                # dbc.FormText(
                #     "Number of times user visited product related section (0-200).",
                #     color="secondary",
                # ),
            ],
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [
                dbc.Label("Product Related Duration", size="md"),
                # dbc.Input(
                #     id="product-related-duration-input",
                #     value="80",
                #     type="text",
                #     debounce=True,
                # ),
                dcc.Slider(
                    id="product-related-duration-input",
                    min=0,
                    max=100,
                    step=1,
                    value=55,
                    marks={
                        0: "0",
                        10: "10",
                        20: "20",
                        30: "30",
                        60: "60",
                        100: "100",
                    },
                ),
                # dbc.FormText(
                #     "Total Time spent in product related section (0-100 min.)"
                # ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
    body=True,
    # color="primary",
    # inverse=True,
)

# Dash app for predicting customer purchasing intention
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.MATERIA])
server = app.server

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        ### first row
        html.Br(),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    html.H1(
                        "Online Shoppers Purchasing Intension Prediction",
                        className="text-center text-primary mb-4",
                    ),
                )
            ],
            # style={"margin": "20px"},
        ),
        html.Br(),
        ### second row
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    [
                        html.H4("By Bhola Prasad"),
                        html.Div(
                            [
                                html.Div(
                                    [
                                        html.A(
                                            "Website",
                                            href="https://www.lifewithdata.com/",
                                            target="_blank",
                                        )
                                    ]
                                ),
                                html.Div(
                                    [
                                        html.A(
                                            "LinkedIn",
                                            href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bhola-prasad-0065834b/",
                                            target="_blank",
                                        )
                                    ]
                                ),
                                html.Div(
                                    [
                                        html.A(
                                            "GitHub",
                                            href="https://github.com/bprasad26/predict-online-shoppers-purchasing-intention",
                                            target="_blank",
                                        )
                                    ]
                                ),
                            ]
                        )
                        # dcc.Markdown(
                        #     "##### Website - [Life With Data](https://www.lifewithdata.com/)",
                        #     className="mb-4",
                        # ),
                    ],
                )
            ],
            justify="start",
        ),
        html.Br(style={"margin-bottom": "50px"}),
        ### Third row
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(controls, md=4),
                dbc.Col(
                    [class_output_card, dcc.Graph(id="shap-waterfall-plot")],
                    md=8,
                ),
            ],
            # align="center",
        ),
        ### Fourth Row
        html.Br(style={"margin-bottom": "50px"}),
        dbc.Row([dbc.Col(decision_tree_card)]),
        ### Fifth Row
        html.Br(style={"margin-bottom": "50px"}),
        dbc.Row(
            [dbc.Col(permutation_imp_card, md=5), dbc.Col(feature_imp_card, md=5)],
            justify="between",
        ),  # 'start', 'center', 'end', 'around' and 'between'.
    ],
    fluid=True,
)


@app.callback(
    Output("shap-waterfall-plot", "figure"),
    [
        Input("page-value-input", "value"),
        Input("exit-rate-input", "value"),
        Input("product-related-input", "value"),
        Input("product-related-duration-input", "value"),
        Input("bounce-rate-input", "value"),
        Input("visitor-type-selector", "value"),
        Input("month-selector", "value"),
    ],
)
def shap_waterfall_plot(
    PageValues,
    ExitRates,
    ProductRelated,
    ProductRelated_Duration,
    BounceRates,
    VisitorType,
    Month,
):

    # load model

    model_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "models", "rf_rnd_search1.joblib")
    model = joblib.load(open(model_path, "rb"))

    visitor_type_index = np.where(X_train_sel.columns == VisitorType)[0][0]
    month_index = np.where(X_train_sel.columns == Month)[0][0]

    x = np.zeros(len(X_train_sel.columns))
    x[0] = float(PageValues)
    x[1] = float(ExitRates)
    x[2] = float(ProductRelated)
    x[3] = float(ProductRelated_Duration)
    x[4] = float(BounceRates)
    x[visitor_type_index] = 1
    x[month_index] = 1
    x_series = pd.Series(x, index=cols_to_use)

    # create a tree explainer object
    explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
    # calculate shap values
    shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x_series)

    fill_color = ["#ff0051" if val >= 0 else "#008bfb" for val in shap_values[1]]
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(
            x=shap_values[1],
            y=cols_to_use,
            text=np.round(shap_values[1], 3),
            orientation="h",
            marker_color=fill_color,
        )
    )
    fig.update_traces(textposition="outside")
    fig.update_layout(
        yaxis=dict(autorange="reversed"),
        xaxis=dict(
            title=f"""P(Buy= {np.round(model.predict_proba([x_series])[0][1],2)})  
            E(Buy= {np.round(explainer.expected_value[1],3)})"""
        ),
        height=600,
        template="simple_white",
    )

    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

The app can be seen on this link - https://customer-purchase-prediction.herokuapp.com/

For reproducing the plots, all the data sets and models can be found in this Github repo - https://github.com/bprasad26/predict-online-shoppers-purchasing-intention

Comment: I can't reproduce this with what you've shared.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden This includes only the code that is used to create the plot that is not showing. If you want to access all of it you can find it here on my Github repo - https://github.com/bprasad26/predict-online-shoppers-purchasing-intention/blob/main/app.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graphs are not loaded because of following issues.

- Numpy issue with shap
- Graphviz binary was missing, which loads the Decision tree graphs

Steps

- Create a runtime.txt file in the root folder add python-3.8.10
- Install all the necessary binaries for the Dash Application

  `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python                                     heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 https://github.com/weibeld/heroku-buildpack-graphviz.git`
- Remove both numpy and shap version from the requirements file so it will install the latest version and fix the dependency issues with shap

`numpy`
`shap`

`heroku logs --tail` output streams of all of its running processes, helps in debugging.

Check out the dashboard https://machine-learning-customer.herokuapp.com/